# How to update a specific index of cipher text in AES OFB mode using openSSL?

Tags: openssl, aes

I am encrypting a stream of characters using AES OFB mode in OpenSSL. If, let's say, I have encrypted 500 characters, can I edit the 20th character and only update the 20th character of ciphertext using OpenSSL instead of decrypting and re-encrypting it? AES OFB mode is independent of cipher text or plain text bits so it should be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

OFB is indeed not dependent on the plain or ciphertext, but each block within the generated key stream **is** dependent on previous block encrypt, starting with the IV value. So to decrypt data at a specific offset you must generate all the blocks up to and including the plaintext block that contains the offset.

In short, the OFB key stream *can* be pre-calculated, but it doesn't offer random access or parallel computation. For random access you *could* use CTR mode, but note that you could attack that mode if you have access to messages that are encrypted with the same IV, especially if those messages are are only different because of changes in time.

There are various disk encryption methods that may be more secure, although those will also at least leak which part of the message is reencrypted (but that cannot really be avoided if you perform partial re-encryption).

Comment: I understand that for decryption, I'll need to generate all blocks. But if I do not want to decrypt but only replace the value at index five like `ciphertext[5] = key_stream[5] XOR new_val_at_5`, is it still not possible? Assuming I have the complete keystream after I encrypted 200 characters, I can update the 5th character by XORing the 5th value of the keystream with the new character and replacing the 5th index of cipher text. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: Uh, yes, replacement can be done, but **only** if you already know the plaintext at the location. In that case you can XOR the ciphertext with the XOR of the old and new plaintext. Of course, an attacker can do the same and retrieve the XOR of the two plaintext, which is often enough to gain a lot of knowledge about both messages. Changing bits at a specific location on unauthenticated ciphertext is called a bit flip attack. It can also be used to gain more information about the other bits if you have a decryption / plaintext oracle available.

Comment: Obviously, you can always flip bits, but if you don't know the plaintext bit then you may not know what you are changing.